# Search Folders and Subfolders for filename containing the words "data" and message box its path

Tags: vbscript

I have A folder on a drive that I require to search (including subfolders) and show in a message box all files that contain a filename of "data" (for example `C:\data\test-data.txt`).

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

CopyUpdater fso.GetFolder("c:\data\")

Sub CopyUpdater(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If LCase(f.Name) = "data" Then
      WScript.Echo objFile.Name
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    CopyUpdater sf
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want partial matches on the filename use [`InStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c) instead of doing a direct comparison. Also, for displaying the path instead of the name you need to echo the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9kfyt6a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property. And of course you need to use the the correct variable.

```
Sub CopyUpdater(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If InStr(LCase(f.Name), "data") > 0 Then
      WScript.Echo f.Path
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    CopyUpdater sf
  Next
End Sub
```